# Array in ng-repeat declartion Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My array:

```
$scope.pages = [{
    "id": "1",
    "names": ["Peter", "Rahul"]
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "names": ["Johnson", "Robert"]
}, ];
```

My Html & Angular

```
<div ng-repeat="page in pages">
     <a>{{page.id}}</a><br />
     <a ng-repeat="name in pages.names">{{page.name}}</a>
</div>
```

I got numbers only in output, it doesn't show the names.

Comment: use `{{name}}` instead of `{{page.name}}`

Comment: And `page.names` instead of `pages.names`.

Comment: Yes works well Thank you very much Gaurav & Deceze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pages.names` should be `page.name`

`{{page.name}}` should be `{{name}}`

---

Change:

```
<a ng-repeat="name in pages.names">{{page.name}}</a>
```

To:

```
<a ng-repeat="name in page.names">{{name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<a ng-repeat="name in page.names">{{name}}</a>` instead of `<a ng-repeat="name in pages.names">{{page.name}}</a>`:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.pages = [{
    "id": "1",
    "names": ["Peter", "Rahul"]
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "names": ["Johnson", "Robert"]
  }, ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="page in pages">
      <a>{{page.id}}</a>
      <br />
      <a ng-repeat="name in page.names">{{name}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```